# How to convert string to xml file in java

Tags: java, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/QuestIPhoneWebService/QuestIPhoneWebService"><LoginResult>&lt;RETURN_VALUE&gt;&lt;ERROR RESULT= '-1' DESC = 'The password entered into the system is not valid. Please check your password and try again.'/&gt;&lt;/RETURN_VALUE&gt;</LoginResult></LoginResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Hi I am getting the value from webservices. I  want to convert above string to xml can anybody tell how to convert string to xml file in java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/QuestIPhoneWebService/QuestIPhoneWebService">
<LoginResult>
&lt;ROOT xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql"&gt;&lt;LOGIN_DETAILS USER_ID="testpub2" COMPANY_ID="1" USER_NAME=" aaa" SYSTEM_USER_ID="6976" USER_EMAIL_ID="hcltestpub2@HSDLGSDMNK0098.com" TOKEN_STRING="A93805F1F1C340F5A8155FDD9B77E595" DISCLAIMER_AGREED="1" USER_ENABLED="1" USER_COMPANY_ENABLED="1" USER_TYPE="2" LOGIN_EXPIRY_DAYS="999" TOKEN_CREATION_DATE="2010-10-01T16:04:26" MOBILE_ENABLED="1" USER_COMPANY_MOBILE_ENABLED="1"/&gt;&lt;COMPANY_DETAILS CLIENT_TYPE_ID="8"/&gt;&lt;USER_SETTINGS&gt;&lt;QUEST_GROUP ID="14293" NAME="World" ASSIGN_NUM="14"/&gt;&lt;INDEX_PROVIDER ID="14251" NAME="QUEST (Default)"/&gt;&lt;STOCK_IDENTIFIER ID="57" NAME="TICKER"/&gt;&lt;/USER_SETTINGS&gt;&lt;PERMISSIONS&gt;&lt;QUEST_FUNCTIONS&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="charting" ID="501" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="modeller" ID="512" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="momentum" ID="513" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="portfolio" ID="516" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="search" ID="518" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="sensitivity" ID="521" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="statistics" ID="524" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="strategy" ID="525" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="summary" ID="526" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="triangle" ID="528" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="valuation" ID="529" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="commentary" ID="530" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="CITN" ID="534" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="batch report" ID="553" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="ModellerWS" ID="557" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="Sector Analysis" ID="562" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;/QUEST_FUNCTIONS&gt;&lt;ADMIN_FUNCTIONS&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="administrator" ID="531" ACCESS="0"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="author" ID="532" ACCESS="1"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="publisher" ID="533" ACCESS="0"/&gt;&lt;FUNCTION NAME="editor" ID="539" ACCESS="0"/&gt;&lt;/ADMIN_FUNCTIONS&gt;&lt;/PERMISSIONS&gt;&lt;/ROOT&gt;
10-04 14:30:08.696: DEBUG/login result is(439): </LoginResult></LoginResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

the child node are coming like this USER_ID="testpub2" I have to convert xnode and get the value how to covert xml node?  and take the value using saxparser. is can I take the value directly?

Comment: You mean write this string into an xml file using java?

Comment: Hmm, "How do I write a string to a file in Java" is not very interesting.  How about how do you write just the contents of the SOAP body (the <LoginResponse> to an XML file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The below code converts a String to an XML document. Once you have the document, you can navigate the nodes or you can write to a file etc.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Util {

    public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
            throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
    }
}
```

Comment: my child node are coming like this  USER_ID="testpub2" I have to convert xml format and take the value how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void writeFile(String yourXML){
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename.xml"));
    try { 
        out.write(yourXML);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that "aString" be yourXML?

Comment: Just to give you some feedback from what I've learned. You should not invoke the close method in the try block. If a exception is thrown you end up with an open file. put it inside your finally block as finally gets called even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: my node format are not coming properly  USER_ID="testpub2" i want to convert xml format and take the value

Comment: Now, it will not compile anymore, because `out` is not defined in the scope of the finally block. If Java made finally blocks easier to use, more people would use them I guess...