# How can i format xml input for restful web service and invoke the service

Tags: web-services, spring, rest

Hi All I expose a service using restFul web service 
  Server side code is

@RequestMapping(value = "/getPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
         public ModelAndView getPerson(@RequestParam("inputXml") String inputXml) {
          -------------------------
           ----------------------------
            }
            return new ModelAndView("userXmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX
                    + String.class, "Test");
        }

Client side implementation  is:

```
        URL oracle = new URL("http://localhost:8081/testWeb/restServices/getPerson?inputXml=input");
         System.out.println("Oracle URl is "+oracle);
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)oracle.openConnection();
         connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml; charset:ISO-8859-1");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);  
     in.close();
```

I able to access the service using  the URL 
      `http://localhost:8081/testWeb/restServices/getPerson?inputXml="input"`
Actually my requirement is, i need to pass xml string as a input like this

```
http://localhost:8081/testWeb/restServices/getPerson?inputXml="<?xml%20version="1.0"%20encoding="UTF-8"%20standalone="yes"?><product><code>WI1</code><name>Widget%20Number%20One</name><price>300.0</price></product>"
```

please help me to find the solution

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888033/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Maya, `/getPerson` is not a RESTful URI name. You should use something like `/person` instead. That way, you can `GET` it or `DELETE` it using HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [RestAssured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Parameters)

```
given().
       formParam("formParamName", "value1").
       queryParam("queryParamName", "value2").
when().
       post("/something");
```

or spring [RestTemplate](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/)

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("count", "5");
restTemplate.getForObject(person, Person.class, vars);
```