# Cannot create XML Document from String

Tags: java, xpages

I am trying to create an org.w3c.dom.Document form an XML string.  I am using this [How to convert string to xml file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888033/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-file-in-java) as a basis.  I am not getting an exception, the problem is that my document is always null.  The XML is system generated and well formed.  I wish to convert it to a Document object so that I can add new Nodes etc.

```
public static org.w3c.dom.Document stringToXML(String xmlSource) throws Exception {

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream input = IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlSource); //uses Apache commons to obtain InputStream
BOMInputStream bomIn = new BOMInputStream(input); //create BOMInputStream from InputStream
InputSource is = new InputSource(bomIn); // InputSource with BOM removed

Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
Document document2 = builder.parse(is);
System.out.println("Document=" + document.getDoctype()); // always null
System.out.println("Document2=" + document2.getDoctype()); // always null

return document;
}
```

I have tried these things:  I created a BOMInputStream thinking that a BOM was causing the conversion to fail.  I thought that this was my issue but passing the BOMInputStream to the InputSource doesn't make a difference.  I have even tried passing a literal String of simple XML and nothing but null.  The toString method returns `[#document:null]`

I am using Xpages, a JSF implementation that uses Java 6.  Full name of Document class used to avoid confusion with Xpage related class of the same name.

Comment: Don't rely on the `toString` method to provide you with useful information

Comment: Thanks, I will try a better test.  I did try several methods other than toString, but nothing too complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on what `toString` is telling you.  It is providing diagnostic information that it thinks is useful about the current class, which is, in this case, nothing more then...

```
"["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]";
```

Which isn't going to help you.  Instead, you will need to try and transform the model back into a `String`, for example...

```
String text
        = "<fruit>"
        + "<banana>yellow</banana>"
        + "<orange>orange</orange>"
        + "<pear>yellow</pear>"
        + "</fruit>";

InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = builder.parse(is);
    System.out.println("Document=" + document.toString()); // always null

    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;
    try {

        os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(os);
        tf.transform(domSource, sr);

        System.out.println(new String(os.toByteArray()));

    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } finally {
        }
    }

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | TransformerConfigurationException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} catch (TransformerException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Document=[#document: null]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fruit>
    <banana>yellow</banana>
    <orange>orange</orange>
    <pear>yellow</pear>
</fruit>
```

Comment: You are right, the output does return my xml file.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also wanted to add that not only did you tell me what you thought the answer was, you gave me the code to prove it.  I really appreciate that and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this: http://www.wissel.net/blog/downloads/SHWL-8MRM36/$File/SimpleXMLDoc.java

Comment: Stephan, thanks!  I will read through this tomorrow, from a cursory look it appears to do a lot of what I need.

Comment: The class probably would be useful a step earlier since it directly allows you to generate XML Step by step in a rather efficient manner. Be clear: since it uses SAX you can't insert DOM elements (that's a different use case)