# Convert a String to XML Element in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, xmlconvert

How do I convert the following string into XML element using JAVA

**String:**
TeacherId=ABCDEFGH&Action=Student&StudentId.Id.1=1001&StudentId.Id.2=1002&ClassRoom=12B&Year=2020

**Excepted Output:**

```
<School>
<ClassRoom>12B</ClassRoom>
    <StudentId>
        <Id>1001</Id>
        <Id>1002</Id>
    </StudentId> 
</School>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888033/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-file-in-java

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an idea?