# Converting XML String to POJO leads to no attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

My function receive's XML but it is formatted as a string, I'm attempting to convert this string into XML and the XML into a POJO. The function will only ever receive one object.

Here's what I got:

```java
String xmlString = "<object><attributeOne>test</attributeOne><attributeTwo>test2</attributeTwo></object>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document xmlObject = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));

// print root element name
System.out.println("Root element: " + xmlObject.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

int numRootElements = xmlObject.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().getLength();
System.out.println("Number of attributes: " + String.valueOf(numRootElements));

// log root element attributes:
System.out.println("Root element attributes: ");
for (int i = 0; i < xmlObject.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().getLength(); i++) {               
    System.out.println(xmlObject.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName() 
    + ": "
    + xmlObject.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue());
}

// Output:
// Root element: object
// Number of attributes: 0
// Root element attributes:
```

I guess I'm not reading the object's values correctly, but I'm confused as to why this is the case when the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3888207/12743194) is no different from my own. Never worked with XML until now

Comment: Is using a library such as Jackson be an option?

Comment: Was attempting to use pure Java, turns out I can read the attributes as nodes instead

Comment: What does that actually mean? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes it is. So rather than using .getAttributes() I used .getNodeValue()

Comment: Great. Then consider adding the solution as an answer and accept it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct this behaviour by using `.getNodeValue()` instead of `.getAttributes()`